# CNN not efficient on my dataset in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a classification of one dimensional data. I presented the data in the form of 549 arrays, each contains 600 samples. I've made a multi-layer perceptron, which showed an efficiency of about 80%. Now I'm trying to do CNN but for some reason it's accuracy doesn't exceed 31%. What can be wrong?

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(600,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_dim = 600))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(Y), epochs = 100, batch_size=8, verbose=1, validation_data=(np.array(X1),np.array(Y1)))

scores = model.evaluate(np.array(X1), np.array(Y1), verbose=0)
```

Input data:

```
X1 = X[:90]
X = X[91:]
Y1 = Y[:90]
Y = Y[91:]
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2)
X1 =np.expand_dims(X1, axis=2)
print(np.array(X).shape)
```

Get the dimension (458, 600, 1) can there be something wrong with the dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```